# knitRBootstrap: zoom options, thumbnail size, and plot size

Tags: r, knitr

Is it possible to change the default zoom level when using knitRBootstrap?

I know in my knitRbootstrap settings I can change the thumbnail size, but that doesn't allow a lot of flexibility as there is a max value:

```
knit_bootstrap_md(input=inputFile, output=outputFile, boot_style = 'cerulean',    
    code_style="Google Code", 
    chooser=NULL, thumbsize = 9, show_code=FALSE)
```

I like the features of knitRbootsrap and prefer it over conventional knitR, but not sure the easiest way to customize image size to allow for certain plots/charts to appear larger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current github version of knitrBootstrap has a chunk option for the image thumbnail size with `bootstrap.thumbnail.size`. They correspond to the [bootstrap grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), the default is `col-md-6`.

The new version is not yet available on CRAN, but you can install it easily with devtools.

`install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
install_github('jimhester/knitrBootstrap')`

Please see the [knitrBootstrap github page](https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap) for full details on all the options and using the new version.